# LINQ to Entities delete exception

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have following code to delete an user from database:

```
var user = from u in db.Users
           where u.Username == username
           select u;

if (user.Count() > 0)
{
    db.DeleteObject(user.First());
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

but I got exception like this:

```
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager sta teManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptChangesDuringSave)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
at MyCompany.SystemSoftware.DQMgr.User.DeleteUser(String username) in C:\workspace\SystemSoftware\SystemSoftware\src\dqm\User.cs:line 479
```

The `Users` table is referenced by few other tables. It is probably caused by the foreign key constraint?

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: @SLaks exception message is in my post.

Comment: That's the stack trace.  What's the message?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this would be to set your Foreign Key constraints to Cascade on Drop, but that's in case you're prepared to lose the referenced records, of course.

Otherwise, you could try to set the properties that represent the relationships to `null` on the user object *and then* delete the user.